# How can I take a variable multiple times and implement counters in while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, printf, scanf

I want this program to determine if given integers are positive/negative & odd/even then increment the counters. But it doesn't work properly.

```
include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int evenCount=0, oddCount=0, posCount=0, negCount=0, zeroCount=0, m;
char x='x';

while(x!='y') {
 printf("enter an integer\n");
 scanf("%d", &m);
 if((m>0)&&(m%2==0)){
     posCount+=1;
     evenCount+=1;
 }
 else if((m>0)&&(m%2!=0)){
     posCount+=1;
     oddCount+=1;
 }
 else if((m<0)&&(m%2==0)){
     negCount+=1;
     evenCount+=1;
 }
 else if((m<0)&&(m%2!=0)){
     oddCount+=1;
     negCount+=1;
 }    
 else {
     zeroCount+=1;    
 }     
 printf("if you want to end the loop write 'y'\n");
 scanf("%c", &x);
}
printf("odd %d \n", &oddCount);
printf("even %d \n", &evenCount);
printf("positive %d \n", &posCount);
printf("negative %d \n", &negCount);
return(0);
}
```

When I run it and give some numbers counts are at millions.

```
enter an integer
123
if you want to end the loop write 'y'
enter an integer
2
if you want to end the loop write 'y'
enter an integer
5
if you want to end the loop write 'y'
enter an integer
y
if you want to end the loop write 'y'
odd 6487572
even 6487576
positive 6487568
negative 6487564
```

The second example.

```
enter an integer
12
if you want to end the loop write 'y'
enter an integer
y
if you want to end the loop write 'y'
odd 6487572
even 6487576
positive 6487568
negative 6487564
```

I'm new to coding and this is my first post on this site also english is not my main language. I'm sorry if made any mistakes.

Comment: `printf("odd %d \n", &oddCount);` should be `printf("odd %d \n", oddCount);` - same for all the other `printf` calls

Comment: There are to many `if`s. Only one if/else is needed to determine if the number is even/odd, and only one if/else is needed to determine negative/positive (assuming `0` belongs to one of these categories. If not, it is just another `if` ). And these checks should be completely decoupled because there is no relation between these two properties.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you need to change this call

```
scanf("%c", &x);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &x);
```

Pay attention to the space before the conversion specifier.

And instead of trying to output addresses

```
printf("odd %d \n", &oddCount);
printf("even %d \n", &evenCount);
printf("positive %d \n", &posCount);
printf("negative %d \n", &negCount);
```

you have to write

```
printf("odd %d \n", oddCount);
printf("even %d \n", evenCount);
printf("positive %d \n", posCount);
printf("negative %d \n", negCount);
```

And it is better to substitute the while loop

```
while(x!='y') {
 //... 
 printf("if you want to end the loop write 'y'\n");
 scanf("%c", &x);
}
```

for do-while loop

```
do {
   //...
   x = '\0';
 printf("if you want to end the loop write 'y'\n");
 scanf(" %c", &x);
} while ( x != 'y' && x != 'Y' );
```